# What is the process for putting animations into questions and answers on stackexchange?

Tags: support

Some answers have nice animations, [for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183985/12558). I have been looking round meta to get guidance on how to post animations and not found any. Is there a post on how to do this?

**Edit**

Thanks to Szabolcs we now have a nice tutorial. The bit that fooled me for a while is the need to have the full definition of the gif i.e (from below).

```
Export["~/Desktop/animation.gif", frames, "GIF", 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "AnimationDurations" -> 1/20]
```

I tried without the `AnimationRepetitions-> Infinity` and just got two shows.

Further, a minor point but again had me fooled, is to use the image inserter on the toolbar. This puts a complicated reference e.g.

```
[![fig1][1]][1]
```

as a placeholder for the video and an even more complicated reference e.g.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsRkK.gif
```

at the end of the post. Thanks for all your help. I guess we can't automate this onto the SE Uploader...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make animated screen captures?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/how-to-make-animated-screen-captures)

Comment: Maybe the functions `CurrentNotebookImage` or `CurrentScreenImage` (new in version 11.3) could be usefull for that. I have tried a little bit but gave up because the cursor was invisible, and that was inacceptable for my animation.

Comment: The question you linked used `ListAnimate`. That means, a list of graphics was available which can easily be exported as gif animation. This is what you see in the post.

Comment: These animations are just [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) or [APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) files (+ other formats?), which are posted like normal images.

Comment: Like halirutan said, what people do is that they generate a list of frames, and then pass that list to `Export`. It is documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GIF.html). You can upload this on Stack Exchange unless it exceeds the maximum file size, which currently is 2 MB. Related question: [27202](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27202/731)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I think it is useful to have a tutorial for those who are less familiar with this topic.** So here it goes.

---

Most animations you see here are [animated GIF files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF). Once you have created the GIF file, it can be posted the same way as any other image.

Mathematica [can export animated GIFs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GIF.html). Here is one example:

```
vp = OptionValue[Graphics3D, ViewPoint]
(* {1.3, -2.4, 2.} *)

frames = Table[
   Plot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, SphericalRegion -> True, 
    ViewPoint -> RotationTransform[theta, {0, 0, 1}][vp]],
   {theta, 0., 2 Pi - 2 Pi/60, Pi/60}
   ];
```

Before you export the frames, you can preview them with [`ListAnimate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html).

```
Export["~/Desktop/animation.gif", frames, "GIF", 
 AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "AnimationDurations" -> 1/20]
```

[image]

---

GIF files are often very large. StackExchange has a 2 MB limit on images. If that is not enough, Google for "GIF optimizer" and use one of the many online services to reduce the file size. For the above animation, I used https://ezgif.com/

---

A different method to create animated GIFs is to create a screen recording. I use [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) for this.

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I have added a couple of elementary points I missed, when I tried, into my question.

Comment: Following this answer I have tried LICEcap. It's very satisifying. Some good points : one sees when the operator is clicking the mouse, the files are very small, I didn't have to change or tune the default parameters. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189056/5467) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189584/5467) are example of use-cases.